# React native sending email direct in android

Tags: android, email, react-native

Is there any way to send email from my **android** app? I'm new in react-native. I searched a lot but the only solution I've found is using an external service using API. There should be a better way!

Please consider that I want to send a complete email, including from, to, subject and text.

Comment: Really? you think an android phone has the capabilities of a mail server?

Comment: you can't be able to do it without api, you need to communicate with the servers and for that you need api

Comment: I can do it in PHP!! I mean I would pay and use a mail server but I'm learning and this is not a paid job.

Comment: If you know Java and are willing to learn how to bridge from native to react-native, you might want to check out JavaMail. It works in native Android apps, I haven't tried in react-native though.

Comment: @Pooya have you tried this https://github.com/angelos3lex/react-native-smtp-mailer? I haven't tried it but yeah same code is looking simple. If you have any idea about it then please share.